# What does this Mosfet Symbol mean (two diodes facing each other at Vgs)?

Tags: mosfet, schematics

The title says it all:
What does this Mosfet Symbol mean (two diodes facing each other at Vgs)? I know its an N-MOS, but I don't understand the meaning/purpose of the two diodes.

Part: AO7404

Datasheet Link: http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO7404.pdf

Picture of the symbol (highlighted part):

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is an ESD clamp, showing that the gate is ESD protected. Typically the back to back diodes are shown as Zeners. This scheme protects against positive and negative ESD hits.

- In the event of a positive ESD event, the top diode is forward biased, and the bottom diode's reverse breakdown voltage will be exceeded. The ESD is shunted to the source, which is often ground.
- In the event of a negative ESD event, the top diode's reverse breakdown voltage is exceeded, and the bottom diode is forward biased. The ESD is again shunted to the source.

Answer (score 5):

Looks little confusing . After looking that the datasheet is from a Chinese supplier one can guess it. edit: That the zener symbol is not correct. [image]

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I thought it migth be clear now as you have already explained it nicely...

Comment: @Adi it's a valid contribution

Comment: Thanks dear placeholder , In the past few years I have dealt with lots of chinese suppliers and they do lots of mistakes in making specs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for more information on this topic, this type of component is often called a [transient-voltage-suppresion (TVS) diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode) and helps reject ESD as @[Matt Young](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/110702/79646) described.

Another example of its use can be found in the schematic of the [u-blox C94-M8P rev B evaluation board](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/C94-M8P-AppBoard_UserGuide_%28UBX-15031066%29.pdf). Note that the TVS diodes are protecting header pins that can be touched by the user.

[image: C94-M8P-B Schematic]